# How do I replace a ceiling fan with pull switch for lights and wall knob for fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

The ceiling/fan had a pull switch and a wall fan on/off knob to adjust speed. I want to put up pendant lights and put a wall switch in.

Comment: It should be as simple as just changing the fan switch to a simple wall switch, but taking pictures showing how the fan switch is wired will help. Turn off the breaker before pulling the switch out for pictures.

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing wiring please?